# Difference when using <? and <?php

Tags: php

I've been wondering what's the difference of using `<? and <?php`. For example in this lines of code.

```
function getWallboard()
{

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
url: "quality_control/qc_ajax.php",
data: "action=get_queue_totals&wallboard=<? echo $_REQUEST['wallboard'];?>",
success: function(msg){
$("#queue_nav").fadeIn("fast");
        $("#queue_nav").html(msg);
    }
});        

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
url: "quality_control/qc_ajax.php",
data: "action=getQCWallboard&qctype=<?php echo $_REQUEST['qctype'];?>&wallboard=<? echo $_REQUEST['wallboard'];?>",
success: function(msg){
$("#wallboard").fadeIn("fast");
        $("#wallboard").html(msg);
    }
});
}
```

I've been getting error for some instance. Like If I change `<? to <?php or <?php to <?`, some of my code block doesn't work.

This is my first post. I hope I can get ideas about the use of this.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php: `PHP also allows for short tags <? and ?> (which are discouraged because they are only available if enabled with short_open_tag php.ini configuration file directive, or if PHP was configured with the --enable-short-tags option. `

Comment: @Akam LOOOL at `...which are discouraged...` the PHP manual is playing games with its users :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first (`<?php`) is a safe open and close tag variation, the second is the so called short-open tag (`<?`, `<?=`). The second one is not always available, use the first option if it's possible. In PHP 5.4, the `<?` is always available regardless the settings.

`<?php` is used to write an actual PHP page. However, `<? ?>` are generally used within HTML code to make easier to read.

**EDIT**

MyFile.php

```
<?php
class MyClass {
    public function MyFunction(){
        $Title = 'my title';
        $Paragraph = 'paragraph';

        include 'MyTemplate.php';
    }
}
?>
```

MyTemplate.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>This is <? echo $Title; ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello - I am a <?= $Paragraph; ?> !</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, you **should** always use `<?php ?>`

Comment: Provide an example on when `<?` is used to make html easier to read? I'm curious to this

Comment: False example. You cannot access `$Title` within the class without calling the class/function

Comment: @DarylGill I am sorry to tell you that but, you are wrong. The include part will work. `$Title` is a local variable. Yes, of course you need to call the class and method but, if I refer to your question, you wanted an example. You have one.

Comment: `<?=` is always valid and is not affected by `short_tags` setting. (it was in the past, but the devs saw value on it and will always be available).

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós As of 5.4, right ?

Comment: @DavidBélanger I think so